# key presses repeat or not register at all, is it Windows or Mobo

Tags: windows-10, motherboard

I changed my motherboard (and CPU+memory) and Windows 10 did some reinstalling upon seeing the changes.

After that, single key presses sometimes result in multiple characters displayed, sometimes none at all.  This happens randomly, not tied to particular keys. A few hours of typing may pass without a single occurrence of the problem, but once it starts, then it is frequent for the next few minutes.

I tried multiple keyboards and multiple USB ports, the problem is always there, so that's not that.

Then it must be a problem with the new motherboard, or Windows 10 getting confused after the motherboard change?  Which of those is most likely causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot with a bootable USB Key.  Any OS and an editor or something to type into.

You may need to temporarily disable Secure Boot.

Type for a while and see if the problem occurs this way.

If yes, then the motherboard is suspect.

If no, then Windows will need a Repair Install using the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

You replaced the motherboard, so it seems most likely Windows needs to be repaired. Use the Windows 10 Repair Install as I noted and use the option to Keep Everything as the first option to try.

Comment: thank you but, it is really hard to reproduce within a "while", and if it does not occur after a "while" it is hard to see how long to keep typing.  I would basically need to type for the whole day straight, to know for sure.  

I can do that, OK, but... do you have a hunch of, is it more likely to be Windows or MoBo?

Comment: You replaced the motherboard, so it seems most likely Windows needs to be Repaired. I amended my answer in this regard.

Comment: right, like I said Windows did reboot several times and it was performing some "repair", as it saw the new mobo.

Comment: A Repair Install is a more thorough procedure.

Comment: I see, I did not realize there was such a thing for Windows 10, as a "repair install", yes, takes about half an hour, definitely faster than replacing mobo or typing forever.  If you put this "repair install" in your answer I will accept it

Comment: Use the option to Keep Everything as that is the best first option for a Repair Install. I did put Repair Install in my answer